# In ASP.Net Core 5.0, how do I route an old .aspx webform to a controller action hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have re-written an old Webforms site into ASP.Net Core 5.0 MVC.  There are thousands of links to the old .aspx pages indexed by search engines.

What is the best way to Route/Redirect the old .aspx pages to the new controller actions.  For example:

The existing link is "https://mywebsite.com/quote.aspx" and I wish to route to "https://mywebsite.com/quote/index".

I found some threads using ASP.Net but can't find a working answer for ASP.Net Core.

Comment: `The existing link is "The existing link is "https://mywebsite.com/quote.aspx" and I wish to route to "https://mywebsite.com/quote/index"." and I wish to route to "https://mywebsite.com/quote/index".`You want to route `https://mywebsite.com/quote.aspx` to `https://mywebsite.com/quote/index`,or you want to migrate from `webform` to `.net core mvc`?

Comment: I've migrated quote.aspx to .net core mvc, therefore it won't exist in production.  It looks like the my best option is IIS Rewrite instead of trying to create a route alternative.